# How do you do data management?

Tags: dataset, data, management

I have about a few million records (small CSV / JSON file) from different sources, with about 50k added everyday. All on my local host.

Until now, I have been using simple file structure to manage them, but it's getting cumbersome. Ideally, I'd like to query files by their meta data (source, type, etc), and pipe that into my ML pipeline (TFX). Id like to keep them local if possible

does anyone have a good solution that you think will work well ?

All the best!

Johnny

Comment: These CSV/JSON files you have, are they downloaded manually and placed in the respective folders? or are they created automatedly by a system?

Comment: Downloaded from the internet, and placed in specific path. The path & file name acts as the metadata currently, which is getting hard to manage

Comment: Since you have a large volume of data constantly added I would suggest your first step must be to try to automate this process. Prepare an ETL pipeline which regularly downloads data from APIs and dumps data to your database. Explore possibility of fetching same info from APIs instead of file downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many experiments, this is what I landed with:

Raw CSV gets converted to Parquet, then Parquet gets stored into Minio.

A few considerations:

1. Parquet files are fast and I don't have to consistently change schema in my code
2. I can use Apache Drill to query Parquet files stored on Minio directly, and then I can use Superset to do analysis

Cheers